# Getting Vevo video information and download links from YouTube

Tags: php, youtube

I am trying to get video information and all other information from YouTube by using this method:

```
$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=' . $my_id;
$my_video_info = curlGet($my_video_info);
```

Most of the time it works, except for [Vevo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vevo) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/c/VEVO/videos). I have googled a lot to figure out the problem and now I think with the URL

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=
```

this method won't work for Vevo videos. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is *"vevo video"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Videos provided by vevo, you know, the largest music video provider in the world?

Comment: There is [a YouTube channel with the name "Vevo"](https://www.youtube.com/c/VEVO/videos) (1539 videos, also linked from www.vevo.com). The last submission was five months ago.

Comment: Can you provide an example (URL) of a Vevo video on YouTube that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze the HTML/JavaScript code of the YouTube page to get the required data, but that is against YouTube's terms of service.

Comment: Do you have a (specific) ***source*** (specific page that mention this)? And/or a quote from said page? Can you add it to this answer (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar)?